# Relationship between parameters of Factor Analysis with categorical data and IRT-parameters

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis, item-response-theory

I have a problem in understanding the relationship between parameters of Factor Analysis with categorical paramters and IRT-parameters. The relationship is clearly defined, for example in

> Kamata, A., & Bauer, D. J. (2008). A note on the relation between factor analytic and item response theory models. Structural Equation Modeling, 15, 136-153.

but when I tried to run a simulation, the results differed and I think I am missing something.

I simulated an IRT model with probit link with

$P_i(Y_i = 1|\theta) = f(\alpha_i(\theta - \beta_i))$.

When running a factor analysis with the WLSMV estimator it uses underlying latent variables for the estimation:

$y^*_i = \nu_i + \lambda_i\theta + \epsilon_i$

$y_i = 
\begin{cases}
1 \text{ if } y^*_i >= \tau_i\\
0 \text{ if } y^*_i < \tau_i
\end{cases}
$

If I run my model with theta-parametrization and a reference indicator for fixing the latent variable, then the relationship between the paramaters should be:

$\alpha_i = \lambda_i\sqrt{\sigma^2_\theta}$

$\beta_i = (\tau_i - \lambda_iE(\theta))/\alpha_i$

However, in my simulation the relationship between my paramters are:

$\alpha_i = \lambda_i$

$\beta_i = \tau_i/\alpha_i$

which should be the conversion for a model where the scale is fixed with $E(\theta) = 0$ and $\sigma^2_\theta = 1$.

I don't know if there is a crucial thing I am missing, but here is my simulation to show the problem:

```
set.seed(1234)

N <- 100000
theta <- rnorm(N,1,2)
item_betas <- c(0,-0.5,-1,0.5)
item_alphas <- c(1,2.0,1.5,0.5)

# P(Yi=1|theta) ## probit link
P1 <- pnorm(item_alphas[1]*(theta-item_betas[1]))
P2 <- pnorm(item_alphas[2]*(theta-item_betas[2]))
P3 <- pnorm(item_alphas[3]*(theta-item_betas[3]))
P4 <- pnorm(item_alphas[4]*(theta-item_betas[4]))

y1 <- rbinom(N,1,prob=P1)
y2 <- rbinom(N,1,prob=P2)
y3 <- rbinom(N,1,prob=P3)
y4 <- rbinom(N,1,prob=P4)

d <- data.frame(y1,y2,y3,y4)

library(lavaan)
model <- '
theta =~ 1*y1 + l1*y1 + l2*y2 + l3*y3 + l4*y4
theta ~~ V_theta*theta
theta ~ E_theta*1

y1 | c(0)*t1 + c(t1)*t1
y2 | c(t2)*t1
y3 | c(t3)*t1
y4 | c(t4)*t1

# reference conversion -> should be correct conversion, but is wrong
r.a1 :=  1 * sqrt(V_theta)
r.a2 := l2 * sqrt(V_theta)
r.a3 := l3 * sqrt(V_theta)
r.a4 := l4 * sqrt(V_theta)
r.b1 := (0  -  1 * (E_theta))/r.a1
r.b2 := (t2 - l2 * (E_theta))/r.a2
r.b3 := (t3 - l3 * (E_theta))/r.a3
r.b4 := (t4 - l4 * (E_theta))/r.a4

# standardized conversion -> should be wrong conversion, but is right
s.a1 := 1
s.a2 := l2
s.a3 := l3
s.a4 := l4
s.b1 := 0 /s.a1
s.b2 := t2/s.a2
s.b3 := t3/s.a3
s.b4 := t4/s.a4
'

m.fit <- sem(model, 
             data=d, ordered=c("y1","y2","y3","y4"), 
             parameterization="theta")
summary(m.fit)
```

Comment: I've only quickly glanced at your code. However, it looks like you simulated $\theta$, which is the latent trait that is assumed to be standard normal in IRT, with mean 1 and variance 2. If you change it to standard normal, do you get the correct results?

Comment: @WeiwenNg Yes, I do. I think I was under the impression that I am generating a sample with an abritary mean and variance, e.g. I could simulate a group which is good at a test and a group which is bad at a test, but the test with it's item parameters are constant. But the reference conversion always fixes the sample $\theta$ to a standard normal distribution. So if I just wanted to check whether my model estimates the simulation parameters or not, I could use the formulas for standardized conversion to keep the latent variable fixed at sample mean and variance?